# No Attribute Error when I run this script to delete my files, but nothing happens

Tags: python-2.7

This code is not printing any Attribute Error and doesnt print anything. I'm trying to find the error with print so I can tell why it's not looping over my files in my directories and deleting them.

```
import os
import glob

def Test():

    path = ('/home/Jack/Python.files/') # Shows the path for all python files
    directories = os.listdir(path) # Finds the directory name

    v = path + directories[0] + ('/*.py~') 
    a = path + directories[1] + ('/*.py~')
    z = path + directories[2] + ('/*.py~')
    w = path + directories[3] + ('/*.py~')
    s = path + directories[4] + ('/*.py~')
    x = path + directories[5] + ('/*.py~')
    # Cocatinates path, directories, and files that end in .py~ together

    numbers = (v, a, z, w, s, x) 
    # Puts the file variables in a tupple

    for i in numbers: 
        if i in path: 
        # Iterates over the tupple for each string file   

            os.remove(i)
            print os.remove(glob.glob(i))
            # Places that string in os.remove and deletes the file

Test()
```

Comment: You imported `glob`, but did you ever consider actually using it?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I actually forgot to add it when posting the code.   This is what i had, and I'm getting an invalid syntax for the Test() call on the final line.

Comment: What does `glob.glob()` return? Can `os.remove()` accept that?

Comment: It takes strings, but it doesn't work when I convert the list to a string either @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: Why do you believe that converting the list to a string would result in a valid filename?

Comment: Because it's a list that contains only one object that is a string of the correct filename.  I am thinking it only has one object in it because I'm calling it as it iterates through the for loop.  When I convert that to a string it should simply be a string that corresponds to the filename

Comment: Have you examined the results of your conversion?

Comment: Yup, I tested the type and same no output, no error, just nothing

Comment: That's nice. Did you *look* at it? With your eyeballs?

Comment: You can never be sure, but I've been lookin at this for 3 hours. So it's probably safe to assume I have